# I want to add background image in WordPress in CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image

My html

```
<section class="banner-area">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

My css

```
.banner-area {
  position: relative;
  background: #f0fffa;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

I want to add background image here.

```
.banner-area:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background: url(../images/bg03.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I think PHP code cannot run in CSS. How can I do this?

Comment: you missed some code here?
(<?= $imagePath ?>)
Im unable to understand how to apply image path here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSS file is located within the WordPress directory somewhere, for example in `wp-content/themes/foobar/example.css`, rename the file to `wp-content/themes/foobar/example.css.php` (append a .php extension!) and prepend the following code to the beginning of the file:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

$pathToBackgroundImage = '../images/bg03.png'; // <- get image path dynamically
?>
```

Now you in fact can execute PHP within the CSS file, while for the browser the output will be CSS due to the Content-Type.

If you don't need the WordPress API to get your background image path, you can omit the `require_once` line. However, if you need to query WP media, it might be good to have it there.
Now you have access to all of WP's functionality as well as being able to dynamically insert the path:

```
.banner-area:before {

  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background: url(<?= $pathToBackgroundImage ?>) no-repeat;
}
```

Then, change the source path to your CSS-file to:
`wp-content/themes/foobar/example.css.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I found a easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. This is best and easy solution

```
<div style="background: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/bg03.png')no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
```